# AWS CLI: When is it necessary to add permission to a SNS topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli, amazon-sns

I'm learning about `AWS`; the specific use-case I'm learning about is having the addition of an object to a `S3` bucket trigger a `SNS` notification that's subscribed to by a `Lambda`, thereby triggering the `Lambda`.

Online reading led me to the [`s3api put-bucket-notification-configuration` page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-notification-configuration.html) which says

> The SNS topic must have an IAM policy attached to it that allows
>   Amazon S3 to publish to it

That led me to the [`sns add-permission` page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/add-permission.html), whose request signature is:

```
  add-permission
--topic-arn <value>
--label <value>
--aws-account-id <value>
--action-name <value>
```

**Question: is it necessary to explicitly add-permission to a `SNS` topic even if the publisher is in the same account in which the topic was created?**
The wording at the linked documentation implies that it is only necessary when the publisher is from a different account, but I'm not certain if I'm interpreting that correctly.

E.g. in my experiments, everything I work with is part of the same account. E.g.:

```
$ aws sns list-topics --profile=admin --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4575
{
    "Topics": [
        {
            "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:my-test-topic"
        }
    ]
}
$
$ aws --profile=lambda-admin --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4574 lambda list-functions
{
    "Functions": [
        {
            "FunctionName": "first_lambda",
            "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:first_lambda",
            "Runtime": "python3.7",
            "Role": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/lambda-role",
            "Handler": "first_lambda.lambda_handler",
            "CodeSize": 311,
            "Description": "",
            "Timeout": 5,
            "LastModified": "2020-06-16T05:10:16.311+0000",
            "CodeSha256": "jRcHzt34ZSDUCyx+INftvu14njRqGeSozKa0Uxv4J98=",
            "Version": "$LATEST",
            "TracingConfig": {
                "Mode": "PassThrough"
            },
            "RevisionId": "af64db69-0b5a-41ad-86c2-8467a60cf618",
            "State": "Active"
        }
    ]
}
```

(I haven't found a way to get the `ARN` of a `S3` bucket from the CLI, but mine is associated with the same account).

Comment: [Configuring Amazon S3 event notifications - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#grant-destinations-permissions-to-s3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: is it necessary to explicitly add-permission to a SNS topic even if the publisher is in the same account in which the topic was created?

The default policy for sqs contains the following:

```
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      }
```

This will allow **any IAM entity** (IAM user, role) from your **account** (the `Condition`; not shown, but present in the policy) to `SNS:Publish` (among other things) to your topic. They still have to have their own permissions to publish though. For example, for lambda you still need to add sns permissions to its executions role, which [confuses people](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=229533).

The important thing to note is the `AWS`. The `AWS` key in `Principal` does not include services, such as `S3`. The reason is that the `Principal` for S3 service looks like this:

```
   "Principal": {
     "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"  
   }
```

Therefore you have to [explicitly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#grant-destinations-permissions-to-s3) allow service `S3` to publish to your topic in the topic's policy.

> I haven't found a way to get the ARN of a S3 bucket from the CLI, but mine is associated with the same account

The bucket ARN has known [format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-arn-format.html):

> arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name

or in China:

> arn:aws-cn:s3:::bucket_name

So even if CLI doesn't explicitly gives the ARN, you can always construct it yourself pretty easily. And if you are not sure if your bucket is in China or not, then you can use [get-bucket-location](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-bucket-location.html) to verify that.