# Failure to set S3 object creation notification to my SNS topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

Looking at AWS documentation, I understood that SNS provides push-based event consumption.

So I assumed that getting notifications for new files in a given S3 bucket should require an SNS topic configuration + event generation from the S3 bucket to that SNS topic.

After creating the topic, I tried to generate the notifications from the bucket too, and
However, after creating the SNS topic, I tried to add event notifications for all object created events in a given S3 bucket to that topic X upon new object creation, and repeatedly failed with the generic error:

```
An unexpected error occurred.
API response
Unable to validate the following destination configurations
```

I tried to pick the SNS topic by ARN (Instead of a dropdown menu) and got the same result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to validate the following destination configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72184474/unable-to-validate-the-following-destination-configurations)

Comment: It didn't unfortunately, but another question did:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418079

My issue was that I had "Principal" set as { "AWS": "*" } at first and it didn't apply to S3 buckets. Changing the principal to { "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com" } resolved it. It's a shame it wasn't clearer from the error that it was a permissions issue and which action was unauthorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418079) about SNS topic permissions.

My issue was that in the topic's access policy I had "Principal" set as:

`{ "AWS": "*" }`

and **it doesn't apply to S3 buckets**.

Changing the principal to:

`{ "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com" }`

resolved the issue.

Would have been nice had the error message been clearer, and it might have saved me some time if I had known earlier this was a permissions issue and which action was unauthorized.